# hbase get from java api giving wrong values

Tags: java, hbase

I created a user table in hbase and entered below values

```
 hbase(main):002:0> create '/mapr/gold1m7cluster/axp/gcp/coddem7/dev/USER','USER_FAMILY'
0 row(s) in 0.0250 seconds

hbase(main):005:0> put '/mapr/gold1m7cluster/axp/gcp/coddem7/dev/USER' , 'User_1' ,  'USER_FAMILY:Id' , '1'
0 row(s) in 0.0020 seconds
hbase(main):006:0> put '/mapr/gold1m7cluster/axp/gcp/coddem7/dev/USER' , 'User_1' ,  'USER_FAMILY:name' , 'Hemanth'
0 row(s) in 0.0030 seconds
hbase(main):007:0>  put '/mapr/gold1m7cluster/axp/gcp/coddem7/dev/USER' , 'User_1' ,  'USER_FAMILY:Bday' , '1999-09-24'
```

The get from Java Api is failing . 
I am using spring boot and hbase template . 
below is the **error**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset (0) + length (4)
>   exceed the capacity of the array: 1
>           at com.mapr.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.explainWrongLengthOrOffset(Bytes.java:595)
>           at com.mapr.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:765)
>           at com.mapr.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:741)
>           at com.hemanth.spring.basics.spring_in_5_steps.UserDaoService$1.mapRow(UserDaoService.java:140)
>           at com.hemanth.spring.basics.spring_in_5_steps.UserDaoService$1.mapRow(UserDaoService.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.RowMapperResultsExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultsExtractor.java:47)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.RowMapperResultsExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultsExtractor.java:30)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate$1.doInTable(HbaseTemplate.java:134)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.execute(HbaseTemplate.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.find(HbaseTemplate.java:129)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.find(HbaseTemplate.java:158)
>           at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.find(HbaseTemplate.java:146)
>           at com.hemanth.spring.basics.spring_in_5_steps.UserDaoService.findAll(UserDaoService.java:137)
>           at com.hemanth.spring.basics.spring_in_5_steps.SpringIn5StepsApplication.main(SpringIn5StepsApplication.java:16)

I tried to print the values retrieved from DB

```
public User mapRow(Result result, int rowNum) throws Exception {
                **System.out.println(" length of the Id is " + result.getValue(CF_INFO, Id).toString().length()) ;
                System.out.println(" the Id is " + result.getValue(CF_INFO, Id).toString()) ;**
                return new User(Math.round( toFloat(result.getValue(CF_INFO, name))),
                        Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, name)),
                        ConvertStringDate(Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, Bday))));
```

I am getting
length of the id is 11
 the id is [B@351d0846

How do I get the right Id ?

Comment: Are you using MapR-DB? Result.getValue would be returning a byte[]. Did you try to print the value using Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, Id))?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue . 
In the below statement Id is stored as string rather than a float value .
We need read it as byte string . convert it to string then to float hence the issue .

User(Math.round( toFloat(result.getValue(CF_INFO, Id)))

Answer (score 0):

**new User(Integer.valueOf( Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO,Id))),**
Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, name)),ConvertStringDate(Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO,Bday))));